# Convert C# regex to python

Tags: python, regex

I'm not sure why this regex will not compile in python 2.7 (re.compile). The re.debug flag won't even show me why.

```
\b(?<case>(review|case|bug[zs]?(\s| )*(id)?:?)s?(\s| )*([#:; ]| )+)((([ ,:;#]|and)*)(?<bugid>\d+))+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in Python, named captures are done with `(?P<name>)`, not `(?<name>)`. Try:

```
\b(?P<case>(review|case|bug[zs]?(\s| )*(id)?:?)s?(\s| )*([#:; ]| )+)((([ ,:;#]|and)*)(?P<bugid>\d+))+
```

Be sure to also use a raw string, e.g. `r'regex'` (which compares with C#'s `@"regex"` syntax).

Note that `(\s| )` is redundant, and can be replaced with `(\s)` or simply `\s` if the capture is not important. Similarly, `([#:; ]| )` can be safely replaced with `([#:; ])`.